# How do I edit the "comments" section of a shortcut file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, shortcut

could you help me with this? I am trying to change the comments section of some shortcuts with PowerShell. If I were to try  `$link.Description = "dog"`, the comments section is changed to "dog". But when I try `$link.Description = $newDescription`, nothing appears in the comments section even though it should say "cat". Here is some of the code:

```
function Set-Shortcut {
  param
  (
  [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$false)]
  $LinkPath = $fileName,#pick the shortcut
  $Hotkey,
  $IconLocation,
  $Arguments,
  $TargetPath,
  $Description
  )

 
  begin {
    $shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
  }#end begin


  process {
    $link = $shell.CreateShortcut($LinkPath)

    $newDescription = "cat"
    
    $link.Description = $newDescription

    $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters.GetEnumerator() |
        Where-Object { $_.key -ne 'LinkPath' } |
        ForEach-Object { $link.$($_.key) = $_.value }
        $link.Save()
  }#end process
}#end Set-Shortcut
```

Comment: What is being passed for `$Description`?  Your pipeline at the end of the `process` block will assign to `$link` all assigned parameters other than `$LinkPath`, which may include `$Description`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, but after changing nothing it seems to be working fine now. Sorry for wasting your time.